# conn = sqlite3.connect('<absolut path>') 0

Tags: python, sqlite, path, absolute

My DB is located here:
D:\sqlite\db

My Python Code is located here:
D:\app\ZAKPRO\R20191121

Code looks this way:

```
import sqlite3
import os.path
conn = sqlite3.connect('D:\sqlite\db\db_name.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("INSERT INTO sts_meta (symbol) VALUES( 'tra' ) ")
```

Error-Message is:
OperationalError: no such table: sts_meta

1. Can anyone help to correct my code?
2. I separate DB and Code in different location: Is that fine and advisable?
3. I only find examples with relative path: Is the access with absolute path not the prefered one in python-sqlite-community? Why is that?

UPDATE
Now I have re-coded, but still facing the same issue:

```
filename = "dbname.db"
dir = "D:\sqlite\db"
dbpath = pathlib.Path(dir, filename)

sql = ("SELECT * from sts_meta")

conn = sqlite3.connect(dbpath)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(sql) 
print(c.fetchall())
conn.commit()
```

This message I receive:
OperationalError: no such table: sts_meta

How to find out wheather I am connected to a database?

Regarding pathlib this is my db-path:
D:\sqlite\db\stocktimeseries.db

Comment: Backslashes are escape-sequences in Python. This could be the problem you're facing here.

Comment: Try replacing the `\ ` with `/` instead and see if that works better.

Comment: It is a windows system. It might be that the suggestion would work different on other OS. Unfortunately it does not work for me

Comment: Python handles the paths the same on all systems. Just change `D:\sqlite\db\stocktimeseries.db` to `D:/sqlite/db/stocktimeseries.db` and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It's not that good to use a relative path.
Good practice would be to use `path.join` from os package in python.

And at any string which contains any characters like backslashes use `r'your string'`. Adding r before your string will state that the special characters contained in the following string is just a string and they serve no other purpose.

I'm not sure if that is what causes this issue. But if the table exists and you are having issues with path, then path.join can help you out.

Comment: It is not solving my problem.